# Prevent WinSCP from uploading .filepart

Tags: sftp, winscp

I have 26 files that I'm trying to upload into an SFTP directory I have 0777 on, and WinSCP seems to stream the file with a `.filepart` extension which it removes once uploaded. The problem I have is that I don't have Rename permissions on the target, so the files fail to upload completely and I'm left with a 1 `.filepart` file each time.

Is there a setting in WinSCP to stream the upload without setting a `.filepart` extension during transmission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more digging after posting the question and found the `Endurance` settings. Toggling

> Enable transfer resume/transfer to temporary filename for

to Disable resolved my issue.

[image]

Comment: See also the documentation for [Automatic Resume / Transfer to Temporary Filename](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#automatic).